# run some javascript code on my website through Visual Studio Code since programming in chrome console is hard

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

let me explain my problem step by step.

1-so i am oppening a my website `http://sharelayer.net/` or **somone else website**

2-i am oppening chrome console and i type `alert("hello world")` and i get this alert inside my website.

3-now i want to do programming for my website and try many line of codes in google chrome and run them in console since it's hard i decide to install a program name vs code.

4-i install vs code => i create a directory =>i open a file and write a simple `alert("hello world")` and i save it => then from File =>Save work space as i save my work space inside same directory=> now i install a vs code plugin from here name debugger for chrome

[image]

now is coming my question part.

5-i go to my file press on F5 (or start debugging from Run>Start Debugging) and then start debugging now i need a configuration file so => i open my script folder and i make a folder with name .vscode =>inside this folder i create a file name launch.json and inside i will put this code

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://viralskills.cc/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "userDataDir": false
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

so now i press on debug and i play start [image]
nothing is happening my alert is not showing inside my chrome browser i tried with config attach and also i added --remote-debugging-port=9222 to my chrome to be able to do debugginn on that port still same and nothing is running in my website and alert not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've missed `<script>` tags
Make sure to use `<script>` `</script>` around your code to show browser it's `JS` code.

```
<script>
alert('Hello World');
</script>
```

Comment: it's not a html file which i am running it's js file which i want to run on top of my website to test some functionionality on top of my site

Comment: @HiDd3N You have to inject that JS with `<script>` tags